# stlport undefined references

Tags: android, stlport

I'm trying to do some work with the version of stlport in the froyo source. I'm getting

```
 stlport/stlport/stl/_alloc.h:158: undefined reference to `std::__node_alloc::_M_allocate(unsigned int&)'
```

and

```
 stlport/stlport/stl/_alloc.h:161: undefined reference to `std::__node_alloc::_M_deallocate(void*, unsigned int)'
```

I found this page and tried the -D flag he recommended, but it didn't work.: http://www.philhassey.com/blog/2010/07/21/android-day-2-the-ndk/

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same problem but including APP_STL := stlport_static didn't help...

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I had the APP_STL := stlport_static in the wrong file. It goes in Application.mk. Not Android.mk. Not too sure why that matters though.

Comment: Thanks! Moved all my APP_* settings into Application.mk solved all the problems!

Answer (score 2):

Its an android ndk problem. Below is the discussion regarding this issue
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-ndk/1Q4Pp5mkpYU/i8iFayGWeOkJ

Bug fixed in the upcoming Release
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16627